# Why is this javascript object undefined?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-mobile

Just as the title says, I can't figure it out.  I've used Jasmine to try to make sure it is defined and it doesn't recognize the file.  Here is the code(btw it's a tutorial online):

```
    Notes.controller = (function ($, dataContext) {
    var notesListSelector = "#notes-list-content";
    var noNotesCachedMsg = "<div>No notes cached</div>";
    var notesListPageId = "notes-list-page";
    var currentNote = null;

    function init() {
        dataContext.init();
        var d = $(document);
        d.bind("pagechange", onPageChange);
    }

    function onPageChange(event, data) {

        var toPageId = data.toPage.attr("id");

        switch (toPageId) {
            case notesListPageId:

                renderNotesList();
                break;
        }
    }

    function renderNotesList() {

        var notesList = dataContext.getNotesList();
        var view = $(notesListSelector);
        view.empty();

        if (notesList.length === 0) {

            $(noNotesCachedMsg).appendTo(view);
        } else {

            var notesCount = notesList.length;
            var note;
            var ul = $("<ul id=\"notes-list\" data-role = \"listview\"></ul>".appendTo(view);
            for (var i =0; i<notesCount; i++) {
                note = notesList[i];
                $("<li>" + "<a data-url =\"index.html#note-editor-page?noteId=" + note.id +
                "\" href=\"index.html#note-editor-page?noteId=" +note.id + "\">" + "<div>" +
                note.title + "</div>" + "<div class=\"list-item-narrative\">" + note.narrative
                + "</div>" + "</a>" + "</li>").appendTo(ul);
            }

            ul.listview();
        }


    };

    return {

        init: init
    }

})(jQuery,Notes.dataContext);
```

I've tried even replacing all of this with the developer's provided source code and it still is undefined, so could this be a software config issue?

Thanks

Comment: What isn't defined?

Comment: you question in undefined, so how can we find your undefined?

Comment: I'm sorry, I know it's vague I'm just pretty lost.  All I can tell as of now is that for some reason this script isn't running at all when I load my page.  I have the right <script> tag in my html.  This script is bound to the "mobileinit" event, and there is a script right before it that executes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're missing a `)` in this line:

```
var ul = $("<ul id=\"notes-list\" data-role = \"listview\"></ul>".appendTo(view);
```

should probably be:

```
var ul = $("<ul id=\"notes-list\" data-role = \"listview\"></ul>").appendTo(view);
```

Also (although unlikely to be the cause of your error), this trailing semicolon isn't required here:

```
function renderNotesList() {
    ...
};
```

Comment: You were right.  The parenthesis was what did it.  I still have a question though:  Shouldn't some of the script have executed?  When I had the error, I put an alert right at the beginning of the where the script was entered, and it never executed.  Thanks for your help btw!

Comment: It was a syntax error which might have prevented the rest of the code executing